# bash - print a line every X seconds (like sed every X lines)

Tags: bash, sed

I know with `sed` you can pipe the output of a command so that you can `print every X lines`.
`make all | sed -n '2~5'`

Is there an equivalent command to `print a line every X seconds`?
`make all | print_line_every_sec '5'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5 seconds timeout read one line and discard anything else:

```
while
   # timeout 5 seconds
   ! timeout 5 sh -c '
     # read one line
     if IFS= read -r line; then
        # output the line
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
        # discard the input for the rest of 5 seconds
        cat >/dev/null
     fi
     # will get here only, if there is nothing to read
   '
   # that means that `timeout` will always return 124 if stdin is still open
   # and it will return 0 exit status only if there is nothing to read
   # so we loop on nonzero exit status of timeout.
do :; done
```

and a oneliner:

```
while ! timeout 0.5 sh -c 'IFS= read -r line && printf "%s\n" "$line" && cat >/dev/null'; do :; done
```

But maybe something simpler -  just discard 5 seconds of data each one line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    timeout 5 cat >/dev/null
done
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r line && 
    printf "%s\n" "$line" &&
    ! timeout 5 cat >/dev/null
do :; done
```

Comment: `timeout 5 cat >/dev/null` what is the input to `cat`? If it's supposed to be `stdin`, shouldn't it be `cat - >/dev/null`?

Comment: `cat -` is equal to `cat`. From [posix cat](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) `If no file operands are specified, the standard input shall be used. If a file is '-', the cat utility shall read from the standard input at that point in the sequence.` but usually [man cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) is simpler: `With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.`

Comment: What does putting `!` on the `timeout` line do?

Comment: `!` inverts the exit status of a command, see [posix exit status](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02_01).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent message every 5 seconds, this is a try :

```
make all | {
    display(){
        if  (( $SECONDS >= 5)); then
            if  test -n "${last_line+x}"; then
                # print only if there is a message in the last 5 seconds
                echo $last_line; unset last_line
            fi
            SECONDS=0
        fi
    }
    SECONDS=0
    while true; do
        while IFS= read -t 0.001 line; do
            last_line=$line
            display
        done
        display
    done
}
```

Comment: The inner while loop may run longer than 5 seconds, as long as there continues to be data to read.

Comment: You can simply set `SECONDS=0` rather than using an additional variable, then check that `$SECONDS > 5`.

Comment: @chepner, updated.  As SECONDS is bash variable, I'd rather leave it.

Comment: Such assignments are a documented use of `SECONDS`. "If a value is assigned to
              SECONDS, the value returned upon subsequent  references  is  the
              number  of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned." Just don't unset `SECONDS` altogether, which destroys its special behavior for that shell session.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the proposed solutions are interesting and beautiful, the most elegant solution IMHO is a **awk** solution. If you want to issue

```
make all | print_line_every_sec 5
```

then you have to create the script *print_line_every_sec* as follows, including a test to avoid an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -le 0 ] ; then echo $(basename $0): invalid argument \'$1\'; exit 1; fi

awk -v delay=$1 'BEGIN {t = systime ()}
  {if (systime() >= t) {print $0 ; t += delay}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed 'e sleep 1' file
```

Print a line every n (in the above example 1 ) second.

To print 5 lines every 2 seconds, use:

```
sed '1~5e sleep 2' file
```

Comment: This doesn't skip lines. I want to only print the latest line every X seconds. This accumulates the `stdout` of my `make all` and prints every line every 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by `watch` command.
If You need only print your output every X second, you could use something like this:

```
watch -n X "Your CMD"
```

if you need to designate any change on your output, it would be useful to use `-d` switch :

```
watch -n X -d "Your CMD"
```

Comment: `Watch is used to run any arbitrary command at regular intervals`. This would call `make` every `X` seconds; that's definitely NOT what I want.

Comment: Hi, dear Bob,  Based on what you asked, You want to "print a line every X seconds ?". So I thought, you need something to monitor some output of your command, otherwise, you should put your command in while loop and in each loop use "sleep X " command to making delay for next round. I'm sorry for my miss understanding.